# is it required babel configuration when I use vite in place of webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, vite, cra

Recently  I was  create  react app  using  vite , it is  lightweight , less config  and  fast  then  compare with  webpack . now  my  question is , is it required  **bable**   configuration in Vite project

Answer (score 7):

No, vite does automatic syntax transforms but it only targets browsers that support es modules (firefox & chrome started supporting it around 2018). If you want to support new js features in older browsers you need to add polyfills though. You can read about the exact behavior and how to support even older browsers [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#browser-compatibility).

Answer (score 4):

No, it is already setup on the background. However if you'd like to adjust Babel's config you can do it. Read the docs here: https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/blob/main/packages/plugin-react/README.md